# add a form into pop up stage (Customize Stage content)

Tags: forms, javafx, stage

I have a button called add new user by hitting that a pop up window should come out containing a add user form . 
Here is my function for that button :

```
public void  btnAddeNewClicked(){


        final TextField name = new TextField() ;
        final TextField addr = new TextField() ;
        final TextField wp = new TextField() ;
        final TextField state = new TextField() ;
        final TextField loginName = new TextField() ;
        final Label labelUsername = new Label();
        final Label labelAddress = new Label();
        final Label labelWebPage = new Label();
        final Label labelState = new Label();
        final Label labelloginName = new Label();
        final Button btn = new Button("Add");


        Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        Scene scene = new Scene(btn);
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.show();


}
```

the problem is I don't know how to add my form into my Stage . Any help is strongly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any of the [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/) to add the content of your popup. Later, add this layout as the root of the scene.

In the following example, I have used a [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button("Show Popup");
        button.setOnAction(e -> btnAddeNewClicked());
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void  btnAddeNewClicked(){

        final TextField name = new TextField() ;
        final TextField addr = new TextField() ;
        final TextField wp = new TextField() ;
        final Label labelUsername = new Label("Username");
        final Label labelAddress = new Label("Address");
        final Label labelWebPage = new Label("Web Page");
        final Button btn = new Button("Add");

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        gridPane.add(labelUsername, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(name, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(labelAddress, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(addr, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(labelWebPage, 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(wp, 1, 2);
        gridPane.add(btn, 0, 3, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btn, HPos.CENTER);

        Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose a suitable layout `Parent` to add your `Node`s to. There are a lot of possibilities, so I just demonstrate it with a very simple one: `VBox`, which just puts the places all children in a vertical row:

```
final TextField name = new TextField() ;
final TextField addr = new TextField() ;
final TextField wp = new TextField() ;
final TextField state = new TextField() ;
final TextField loginName = new TextField() ;
final Label labelUsername = new Label();
final Label labelAddress = new Label();
final Label labelWebPage = new Label();
final Label labelState = new Label();
final Label labelloginName = new Label();
final Button btn = new Button("Add");

VBox root = new VBox();
root.getChildren().addAll(name,
                          addr,
                          wp,
                          state,
                          loginName,
                          labelUsername,
                          labelAddress,
                          labelWebPage,
                          labelState,
                          labelloginName,
                          btn);

Stage dialog = new Stage();
dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
dialog.setScene(scene);
dialog.show();
```

Note that these layouts could be used as children of other layouts too, if a more complex layout is needed. Using SceneBuilder may be easier for a beginner, but you should know how the layouts position the children regardless. It's easy to see the child-parent relationships in the resulting fxml file reproduce the same layout in java code.